# Python - Change value at memory address

Tags: python, memory, ctypes

For example, I have a variable called `a`, and need to change it by its memory address:

```py
a: str = "hello"
address: int = id(a)

change_by_address(address, a, 'newval') # is something like this possible?
```

Is there some way to do this, perhaps in the `ctypes` library?

Comment: How about `globals()["a"] = "world"`? Would that fit your needs? There is also a `locals()` version of that as well.

Comment: pedantically, `id()` is not guaranteed to be the memory address of the object, and [this is an implementation detail of CPython](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) (though this is almost always the case)

Comment: Yes, there is. I recently [did it with ints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70882093/12671057) and you can similarly do it with strings. But you shouldn't. Why do you think you need to?

Comment: Here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63970638/235698) where you can do this in CPython, and also demonstrates why you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, positively not.  That ID is an address of SOMETHING in memory, but in C terms these are all moderately complicated data structures.

Python is not C.  You cannot think of things in the same way.

Comment: At least in CPython, you *can* do it, but corrupting what is in the OP's case an immutable `str` is definitely a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can read by address in python:

```py
import ctypes


a = 10
memfield = (ctypes.c_int).from_address(id(a))
print(memfield) # c_int(15)
```

But as far as I know, you cannot change values by address.