# Override return value in str subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a string-like class that acts like `str` but takes the value from the attribute of an object where that value has not been set yet but will have been set before the string-like object is read from.

```python
from __future__ import annotations

from functools import wraps
from inspect import getmembers, isroutine
from typing import Any, Callable, Dict, Final, Optional, Self, Tuple, Type, override


def _wrapper(func: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[..., Any]:
    @wraps(func)
    def method(self: DeferredStr, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        self._load()  # pyright: ignore[reportPrivateUsage]
        value = self._value  # pyright: ignore[reportPrivateUsage]
        assert value is not None
        return func(value, *args, **kwargs)
    return method


class _DeferredStrMetaclass(type):
    NON_WRAPPED_METHODS: Final[Tuple[str, ...]] = (
        "__class__",
        "__class_getitem__",
        "__delattr__",
        "__dir__",
        "__doc__",
        "__getattribute__",
        "__getstate__",
        "__init__",
        "__init_subclass__",
        "__new__",
        "__repr__",
        "__setattr__",
        "__subclasshook__",
    )

    def __new__(
        cls,
        clsname: str,
        bases: Tuple[Type[Any], ...],
        attrs: Dict[str, Any],
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> Self:
        for attr, value in getmembers(str, predicate=isroutine):
            if (
                attr not in attrs
                and attr not in _DeferredStrMetaclass.NON_WRAPPED_METHODS
            ):
                attrs[attr] = _wrapper(value)

        return super().__new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs, **kwargs)


class DeferredStr(str, metaclass=_DeferredStrMetaclass):
    _value: Optional[str]
    _instance: object
    _attributes: Tuple[str, ...]
    _expect_str: bool

    def __new__(
        cls,
        __instance: object,
        *__attributes: str,
        __expect_str: bool = True,
    ) -> Self:
        return super().__new__(cls, "not this")

    def __init__(
        self,
        __instance: object,
        *__attributes: str,
        __expect_str: bool = True,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._value = None
        self._instance = __instance
        self._attributes = __attributes
        self._expect_str = __expect_str

    def _load(self) -> None:
        if self._value is not None:
            return
        value = self._instance
        for attribute in self._attributes:
            value = getattr(value, attribute)
        if isinstance(value, str):
            value = str(value)
        elif self._expect_str:
            raise TypeError(f"{repr(self)} is not a str.")
        else:
            value = repr(value)
        self._value = value

    @override
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "<{name}: {instance}, {attributes} = {value}>".format(
            name=type(self).__name__,
            instance=repr(self._instance),
            attributes=repr(self._attributes),
            value=repr(self._value),
        )

    @override
    def __eq__(self, __value: object) -> bool:
        if isinstance(__value, DeferredStr):
            return (
                self._instance == __value._instance
                and self._attributes == __value._attributes
            )
        self._load()
        value = self._value
        assert value is not None
        return value == __value
```

This "works" up to a certain point:

```python
class Test:
    value: Optional[str] = None

instance = Test()
deferred_str = DeferredStr(instance, "value")
# sometime later ...
instance.value = "1"

print(deferred_str + "2")
print("".join(deferred_str))
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 12
> 1
> ```

Which is as-expected; but, if the sub-class is on the right-hand side of the operator:

```python
print("2" + deferred_str)
print("".join((deferred_str,)))
```

Then the output is:

> ```
> 2not this
> not this
> ```

I understand why this is happening as the function calls are the equivalent of:

```python
print(DeferredStr.__add__(deferred_str, "2"))
print("".join(DeferredStr.__iter__(deferred_str)))
print(str.__add__("2", deferred_str))
print(str.join("", (deferred_str,)))
```

and when a `DeferredStr` method is called then deferred value is substituted for the super-classes value and when the `str` method is called it is taking the underlying value passed from the `DeferredStr` constructor to the `str` constructor.

I know that I can fix it by wrapping the sub-class in a `str()` call everywhere it is going to be used:

```python
print("2" + str(deferred_str))
```

Is there any way to fix `DeferredStr` (or rewrite it) so that the code works on both the left- and right-hand sides of operators without having to wrap it in `str()`?

*(Note: any modifications should also pass type-checking in MyPy and Pyright.)*

My current expectation is that this is not possible and that, if it is going to be necessary to wrap the class in `str()` then, it would be better to not inherit from `str` (and maybe inherit from `collections.UserString` instead) so that the type-checkers will pick when it is used as an argument for something that expects a `str` and hasn't been wrapped in a call to `str()`. However, I'm (faintly) hoping that someone familiar with the inner workings of Python might have a suggestion for an alternative solution.

Comment: You're basically trying to create a mutable string, which simply isn't going to happen for a `str` subclass unless you do something extremely [hacky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63970638/6890912). Gotta settle with a `collections.UserString` and wrap it with `str` as needed instead.

Comment: @blhsing I would have said that I want to have 2 immutable strings; the first is set when the class instance is created and I then want to forever ignore it and the second is set at a later time (but before the class used as a source to read from) and whenever I read from the class I would want to read that second immutable string. I understand that it is likely impossible and that it may give the appearance of a mutating string (but the underlying byte arrays of the strings will never mutate).

Comment: Regardless of what the underlying data structures do or don't do, the object containing them is still behaving differently at one point then at another, so the *object itself* is mutable and thus (almost certainly) can't be a `str` subclass. I agree with blhsing that a mutable object that holds two strings as attributes is probably the best you can do.

Comment: I don't really know what your ultimate use case is, but it definitely seems like a simpler route to do something similar to what you're showing is to make `instance.value` a `@property` that returns some default string value if it hasn't been set.

Comment: @CrazyChucky The use case is complicated - there is a class defining a property that may have build errors during initialisation that means it is invalid but the detailed information to raise an exception about the error is not set on that property class until the class containing the property is also constructed (via a meta-class) and then all the build errors for the properties should be aggregated and raised on that containing class (rather than on the individual properties). ...

Comment: ... It doesn't make sense, in this case, to return a default value. It has to be the value that hasn't been set yet; hence the use of a wrapper to get the deferred value to be used once the containing class is built. But it is being passed to functions that expect strings which I why I was trying to keep it as something that can just be treated as if it was a string. I can rewrite all those functions to take multiple types but it would be simpler to have something that quacks like a `str`.

Comment: ...I'm afraid you lost me. While it seems like the answer to the immediate question was "No, it's not possible," you might get something helpful if you zoom out a little and post a question explaining that situation. It might even be a good fit over on Software Engineering.

Answer (score 4):

Since `str` instances are immutable, normally it would not be possible to make an `str` object "appear" to be of a different value in operations that access its value directly as an `str` object.

But since your use case is really to "monitor" changes made to a particular attribute of an instance, it is then possible to install a monitor through a descriptor such that setting the attribute would replace all references to the deferred string with the new given value by finding the referrers through `gc.get_referrers`, which, conveniently, can be done through the `replace_all_refs` function of the [`pyjack`](https://pypi.org/project/pyjack/) module.

Since `pyjack` was originally written for Python 2 I refactored its `replace_all_refs` function for Python 3 as follows:

```
import gc
import types
import inspect

def proxy0(data):
    def proxy1(): return data
    return proxy1

_CELLTYPE = type(proxy0(None).__closure__[0])

def replace_all_refs(org_obj, new_obj):
    gc.collect()

    hit = False
    for referrer in gc.get_referrers(org_obj):
        if isinstance(referrer, types.FrameType):
            continue
        if isinstance(referrer, dict):
            cls = None
            if '__dict__' in referrer and '__weakref__' in referrer:
                for cls in gc.get_referrers(referrer):
                    if inspect.isclass(cls) and cls.__dict__ == referrer:
                        break
            for key, value in referrer.items():
                if value is org_obj:
                    hit = True
                    value = new_obj
                    referrer[key] = value
                    if cls:
                        setattr(cls, key, new_obj)
                if key is org_obj:
                    hit = True
                    del referrer[key]
                    referrer[new_obj] = value
        elif isinstance(referrer, list):
            for i, value in enumerate(referrer):
                if value is org_obj:
                    hit = True
                    referrer[i] = new_obj
        elif isinstance(referrer, set):
            referrer.remove(org_obj)
            referrer.add(new_obj)
            hit = True
        elif isinstance(referrer, (tuple, frozenset,)):
            new_tuple = []
            for obj in referrer:
                if obj is org_obj:
                    new_tuple.append(new_obj)
                else:
                    new_tuple.append(obj)
            replace_all_refs(referrer, type(referrer)(new_tuple))
        elif isinstance(referrer, _CELLTYPE):
            def proxy0(data):
                def proxy1(): return data
                return proxy1
            proxy = proxy0(new_obj)
            newcell = proxy.__closure__[0]
            replace_all_refs(referrer, newcell)
        elif isinstance(referrer, types.FunctionType):
            localsmap = {}
            for key in ['__code__', '__globals__', '__name__',
                        '__defaults__', '__closure__']:
                orgattr = getattr(referrer, key)
                if orgattr is org_obj:
                    localsmap[key[2:-2]] = new_obj
                else:
                    localsmap[key[2:-2]] = orgattr
            localsmap['argdefs'] = localsmap['defaults']
            del localsmap['defaults']
            newfn = types.FunctionType(**localsmap)
            replace_all_refs(referrer, newfn)
    if hit is False:
        raise AttributeError("Object '%r' not found" % org_obj)
    return org_obj
```

And here's the descriptor and `DeferredStr`, a subclass of `str` that installs the descriptor on the given attribute of the type of the given instance:

```
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary

class DeferredStrProperty:
    instances = WeakKeyDictionary()

    def __init__(self, attribute):
        self.attribute = attribute

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return vars(objtype)[self.attribute]
        if (deferred_str := self.instances.get(obj)) is None:
            return vars(obj)[self.attribute]
        return deferred_str

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if (deferred_str := self.instances.get(obj)) is None:
            vars(obj)[self.attribute] = value
        else:
            replace_all_refs(deferred_str, value)
            del self.instances[obj]

class DeferredStr(str):
    def __new__(cls, instance, attribute):
        if not isinstance(getattr(type(instance), attribute), DeferredStrProperty):
            setattr(type(instance), attribute, DeferredStrProperty(attribute))
        DeferredStrProperty.instances[instance] = s = super().__new__(cls, 'x')
        return s
```

so that:

```
from typing import Optional

class Test:
    value: Optional[str] = None

instance = Test()
instance2 = Test()
deferred_str = DeferredStr(instance, "value")
print("2" + deferred_str)
print("".join((deferred_str,)))
print(instance.value)
print('some time later...')
instance2.value = '3'
instance.value = '1'
print(instance2.value)
print(deferred_str)
print(deferred_str + "2")
print("".join(deferred_str))
print("2" + deferred_str)
print("".join((deferred_str,)))
```

outputs:

```
2x
x
x
some time later...
3
1
12
1
21
1
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/S1en5h

Comment: Wow! You're a wizard.